# Accessing an instance variable from another class -- can I use a class method?

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

I need to access to a `NSMutableArray`, in `class1`, from another class (`class2`). The solution I tried was to create a class method in `class1` and call it from `class2`. Obviously, it is not possible because this is a restriction of class methods. I cannot figure out the solution. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you expose needed instance variables through properties.

This link covers properties.

http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Once the correct variables are exposed then simply pass a reference to the needed class to a given method.

Comment: Thanks you. That's solve my question :)

I already tried the properties but I can't remember why I had errors. Now I try it again and works. Sorry for the 'stupid question'

Comment: No problem. If you feel this answer best meets your answer please select it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Not surprisingly, you need an instance in order to access an instance variable. You can make that instance a *singleton* if it fits your design, or make the variable you increment `static` rather than ivar, which will make it accessible directly from a class method.

If there are multiple instances that you need to access from a class method, you need some sort of a *registry* for your objects, such as an `NSDictionary` that maps your objects by keys.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the instance variable to a class method as a parameter should solve the problem.
Edit: If class1 and class2 are just instances then you will need a class variable.